UniVocity is not releasing memory
I need to compare 2 huge csv file contents based on certain preprocessing... i have done with my logic but process takes much time for huge files so i used univocity Parser it performs faster but it seems not releasing the memory after the process completion
try (BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile))) {             List<Map<String, String>> batchRecords = new ArrayList<>();             CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();             parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);             parserSettings.getFormat().setDelimiter(compareFileMetaData.userDelimiter);             parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);             parser.beginParsing(fileReader);             String[] headers = parser.getContext().headers();             System.out.println(" header processing ......");             headers = Arrays.stream(headers)                     .map(header -> header.replaceAll("\\p{C}", "").toLowerCase())                     .toArray(String[]::new);             Map<String, String> row;             Record record;             int i=1;             while ((record = parser.parseNextRecord()) != null) {                 row = record.toFieldMap(headers);                 batchRecords.add(row);             if (batchRecords.size() == BATCH_SIZE) {                 ....process batch records }                 batchRecords.clear();                 }              finally {             if (parser != null) {                 // Close the parser and writer to release resources                 parser.stopParsing();             } 

note for each file I'm using two Linked Hash map for setup configuration comparison this maps will have file content with process data as value  after process ended i cleared the map too but memory is not being released but my previous version code released the memory in this version only used uniVocity library to increase the performance
